# Recruiter inviting me for an interview - no sufficient skills for the position

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

I got invited for an interview by a recruiter through LinkedIn. They said that they were looking for experienced web dev with additional Java knowledge.

I have a few years of web development experience, however I've never touched Java in my life nor I have it listed on my LinkedIn. When I investigated the open vacancy on the internet, it also required some back-end knowledge which is contrast to what I do - front-end development.

What should I expect from this kind of an interview? Since it feels like the recruiter just skimmed through my profile without actually reading anything, should I still accept it and risk being embarassed?

UPDATE: Went for the interview and nailed it.

Comment: You can always ask for details, or just attend the interview to see what it's about. We can't tell you what to expect, or whether to accept it.

Comment: I mean, you were asked for the interview - it's not your fault if they don't know what they're doing. Just accept and check it out.

Comment: This happens all the time!
Recruiter: "you'd be great for this position. It requires experience in x,y,z"
Me, with no experience of x,y,z, secretly, nor publicly, rolling my eyes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all is the company or the position of interest to you? And do you have time to go for an interview?
Then go. You have nothing to lose and it doesn’t hurt to brush up on interviewing skills especially if you have been with the same company for a while.
Worse case is the recruiter hands your resume to a hiring manager and because of the lack of experience you mentioned never actually call you

Comment: If nothing else OP will get a training in interviewing. Never hurts to polish your skills. If OP has a time for that, and is OK nothing else will come out of it.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like it may be a recruiter that is attempting to meet his 'quota'. I would go through with the interview if it is somewhere that you'd like to work though. As others have said, worse thing that can happen is they say 'no'.

Just be up front and honest about your qualifications from the start. Interviewing is an art and the practice you get from doing interviews is something you can't get anywhere else, other than interviews.

Comment: What quota? The recruiter is wasting time if he does not place the candidate. He is also getting himself a bad reputation with the client if he sends candidates who are patently a bad match. His agency might have a quota for placements, but they won't have one for interviews.

Answer (score 4):

One thing no one else seems to have mentioned is: is Java something you would like to learn?  If so, and the subject comes up at the interview, admit you don't know much but add that you are very willing to learn.  In my experience, that kind of 'can do' willingness can sound good to interviewers.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with the above two posts.  Any gap between posted requirements and your skillsets is the responsibility of the recruiter handling this, and not you.

I've been a hiring manager before, and know very well that..

- Many recruiters don't know technical skillsets very well, and will often miss things.  Pretty sure that six months earlier some of them were waiting on tables or selling used cars.  This is why I'll review resumes before agreeing to an interview.
- Many recruiters will 'scramble' a candidates resume to make it look more attractive, and sometimes have the opposite effect, so if someone is close I'll give a little latitude in interviewing them.
- There are other needs in my company, and if I can find a match between a job candidate and another department in my company I will do my best.  For example, what I know about Java can be written on the back of a matchbook cover with a grease pencil using large letters, but I do know the AppDev hiring manager and can refer candidates.

Good luck.
Jim